# R reading data from Elastic

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am reading some records from Elastic into R and it is turning out to be painfully slow.

Context - The data is for a property marketplace. The table I am reading is for property views (i.e. when someone clicks on a property to see details). I need to capture property ID and view date & time for analytics.

This is what I am doing:

1. Extract the data from Elastic into a list

   ```
   query <- sprintf('{"query":{"range":{"time":{"gte":"%s","lte":"%s"}}}}',start_date,end_date)
   view_list <- elastic::Search(index = "organised",type = "PROPERTY_VIEW",size = 10000000,body=query)$hits$hits
   ```
2. Extract the list into fields in a data frame

   ```
   number_of_views <- length(view_list)
   a <- 1 
   view_data <- data.frame(view_date=as.Date(character()),
                            propertyId=character())
   view_date = vector(mode = "character",length = 0)
   propertyId = vector(mode = "character",length = 0)

   while (a <= number_of_views) {
     view_date[a] <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(view_list[[a]][[6]]$time/1000, origin="1970-01-01"))                      
     propertyId <- as.character(view_list[[a]][[6]]$propertyId)
     a <- a+1
   }
   view_list_df <- data.frame(trackId,userId,viewId,view_date,requestId,propertyId)
   ```

Speed - To read 1 week's of data (500k records) is taking 7-8 minutes. this is just too slow.

list sample:

```
> head(dput(view_list[1:10]))
list(structure(list(`_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", 
    `_id` = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "8e370fe75121cda0cccda2f1934c7051", userId = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13", 
        id = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9", 
        time = 1437351878754, requestId = "1437351878754", propertyId = "ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa:ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa", userId = NULL, 
        id = "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa:ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78", 
        time = 1437351694070, requestId = "1437351694070", propertyId = "ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37", userId = NULL, 
        id = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b", 
        time = 1437351931929, requestId = "1437351931929", propertyId = "ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37", userId = NULL, 
        id = "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571", 
        time = 1437351964188, requestId = "1437351964188", propertyId = "ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4:ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4", userId = NULL, 
        id = "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4:ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161", 
        time = 1437353794879, requestId = "1437353794879", propertyId = "ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "91bbfe57428a47ce2233da1b5517b9a1", userId = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13", 
        id = "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535", 
        time = 1437353798036, requestId = "1437353798036", propertyId = "ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "830f0fe6d53c58938d876175ceca357c:ff8081814e71b801014e72a340300b74", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "830f0fe6d53c58938d876175ceca357c", userId = NULL, 
        id = "830f0fe6d53c58938d876175ceca357c:ff8081814e71b801014e72a340300b74", 
        time = 1437355401546, requestId = "1437355401546", propertyId = "ff8081814e71b801014e72a340300b74"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "88200b3e1bc22cb4b270f89810cd8f32:ff8081814db00698014db29fb80d0614", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "88200b3e1bc22cb4b270f89810cd8f32", userId = NULL, 
        id = "88200b3e1bc22cb4b270f89810cd8f32:ff8081814db00698014db29fb80d0614", 
        time = 1437355324426, requestId = "1437355324426", propertyId = "ff8081814db00698014db29fb80d0614"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "2e9afe62406bedbf90d14fd22a6296de:ff80808149f1ccdc0149f4dd916500e2", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "2e9afe62406bedbf90d14fd22a6296de", userId = NULL, 
        id = "2e9afe62406bedbf90d14fd22a6296de:ff80808149f1ccdc0149f4dd916500e2", 
        time = 1437355340320, requestId = "1437355340320", propertyId = "ff80808149f1ccdc0149f4dd916500e2"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")), structure(list(
    `_index` = "organised", `_type` = "PROPERTY_VIEW", `_id` = "357c4a9917b47635a6dba600805861f4:ff80808149e225cd0149e2ba48d5009c", 
    `_version` = 1L, `_score` = 1, `_source` = structure(list(
        trackId = "357c4a9917b47635a6dba600805861f4", userId = NULL, 
        id = "357c4a9917b47635a6dba600805861f4:ff80808149e225cd0149e2ba48d5009c", 
        time = 1437355340832, requestId = "1437355340832", propertyId = "ff80808149e225cd0149e2ba48d5009c"), .Names = c("trackId", 
    "userId", "id", "time", "requestId", "propertyId"))), .Names = c("_index", 
"_type", "_id", "_version", "_score", "_source")))
[[1]]
[[1]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[1]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[1]]$`_id`
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"

[[1]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[1]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[1]]$`_source`
[[1]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "8e370fe75121cda0cccda2f1934c7051"

[[1]]$`_source`$userId
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13"

[[1]]$`_source`$id
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"

[[1]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437351878754

[[1]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437351878754"

[[1]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"



[[2]]
[[2]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[2]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[2]]$`_id`
[1] "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa:ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78"

[[2]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[2]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[2]]$`_source`
[[2]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa"

[[2]]$`_source`$userId
NULL

[[2]]$`_source`$id
[1] "6b2eaf11c2e4ba6be7c3bd109d8905aa:ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78"

[[2]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437351694070

[[2]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437351694070"

[[2]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814d5bcfaa014d62b622352d78"



[[3]]
[[3]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[3]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[3]]$`_id`
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b"

[[3]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[3]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[3]]$`_source`
[[3]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37"

[[3]]$`_source`$userId
NULL

[[3]]$`_source`$id
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b"

[[3]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437351931929

[[3]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437351931929"

[[3]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814d28f714014d31eb92a2210b"



[[4]]
[[4]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[4]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[4]]$`_id`
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571"

[[4]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[4]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[4]]$`_source`
[[4]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37"

[[4]]$`_source`$userId
NULL

[[4]]$`_source`$id
[1] "84879c86112f53f1124a1f9cb83d6b37:ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571"

[[4]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437351964188

[[4]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437351964188"

[[4]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814ca1cc06014ca2b9823c0571"



[[5]]
[[5]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[5]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[5]]$`_id`
[1] "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4:ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161"

[[5]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[5]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[5]]$`_source`
[[5]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4"

[[5]]$`_source`$userId
NULL

[[5]]$`_source`$id
[1] "38212cb8dbd60c10d356fe30257932b4:ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161"

[[5]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437353794879

[[5]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437353794879"

[[5]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814d42cfff014d473b7f071161"



[[6]]
[[6]]$`_index`
[1] "organised"

[[6]]$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

[[6]]$`_id`
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535"

[[6]]$`_version`
[1] 1

[[6]]$`_score`
[1] 1

[[6]]$`_source`
[[6]]$`_source`$trackId
[1] "91bbfe57428a47ce2233da1b5517b9a1"

[[6]]$`_source`$userId
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13"

[[6]]$`_source`$id
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535"

[[6]]$`_source`$time
[1] 1437353798036

[[6]]$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437353798036"

[[6]]$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814d891540014d8eac50142535"
```

Comment: You should initialize your vectors length with `number_of_view` instead of 0 to avoid growing it inside the loop. Benchmark of solutions could be easiest with an example dataset of `view_list`

Comment: @Pascal - Format of the view_list is : `code` > view_list[[1]]
$`_index`
[1] "organised"

$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_VIEW"

$`_id`
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"

$`_version`
[1] 1

$`_score`
[1] 1

$`_source`
$`_source`$trackId
[1] "8e370fe75121cda0cccda2f1934c7051"

$`_source`$userId
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13"

$`_source`$id
[1] "ff8081814ea04efe014ea6843b7f3d13:ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9"

$`_source`$time
[1] 1437351878754
$`_source`$requestId
[1] "1437351878754"
$`_source`$propertyId
[1] "ff8081814e5cc5af014e5ce7dff202a9" `code`

Comment: Please [edit] your question, comments are ugly for code. If you don't mind posting real data, a `head(dput(view_list[1:10]))`may be great (try to adapt the rage to keep something reasonable inside the question.

Comment: Why do you reply to me?

Comment: @Pascal I assume Op didn't saw the editor and comment author was not the same person. (Hopefully I keep getting back there to follow up my comment :p)

Comment: @Tensibai Fortunately for the OP.

Comment: I edited the code with an example of the list. Any suggestions to spped things up appreciated

Comment: @GauravChaturvedi  Did you figure this out? i'm the `elastic` author if you need any help. Opening an issue at the repo https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues may be faster

Comment: @sckott - I havent figured this out yet. I am not sure of this is an issue or gap in my understanding. I will try the repo out. Thanks for letting me know